# Configuration Periodic Reincarnation Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, plugins, configuration

I am trying to rebuild all my failed jobs in Jenkins during night. For this purpose I installed the plugin **Periodic Reincarnation Plugin**, but doesn't matter how I configure it, I never get it to use the cron expression. This is my actual configuration:

[image]

I would expect the plugin to launch my jobs at:

- next at 2017-03-07 02:00:00
- then at 2017-03-07 03:00:00
- then at 2017-03-07 04:00:00
- then at 2017-03-07 05:00:00then at 2017-03-07 06:00:00

But none of them are executed.

I have just configured the plugin globally, not locally on each job.

Any hints on what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found the solution:

[image]

I am not really sure what is the difference between **Node Action** and **Master Action** fields, but with this configuration I get all failed jobs, whose name ends in "release", rebuilt nightly.

Hope it helps someone else!

Comment: Note that this plugin does not work with folders, I opened the following issue:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42797?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20component%20%3D%20periodic-reincarnation-plugin